# TLS over Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, core-bluetooth, tls1.2

I need to talk to a peripheral via Bluetooth. A device for which we also control the firmware.

We have been asked to secure the data that is transmitted between the central (iOS device) and the peripheral.

We need to build the encryption ourselves. The peripheral developers and the project manager agreed on using the TLS handshake.

I've spent the last few days searching for solutions. All libraries that I found rely on sockets. The examples where about IP networking.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of Bluetooth communication? Does anyone have suggestions for librairies that allows TLS implementation in iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you use public key cryptography. If your case is like the web, where the server needs to authenticate to the client, but the client can be anyone, you can have a server certificate. The server sends the certificate to the client, the client verifies it, and they negotiate on a session key. This method is also not very different to how TLS works. If you want to authenticate the client as well, you can have client certificates as well, but this might not be a good idea if they can easily be extracted from the device.

Comment: @jackgu1988 in my case the iOS device is the client and the remote peripheral is the server. Am i right ? Could you suggest iOS librairies or Frameworks for this ?

Comment: HI please, i am facing the same issue , did u solve it ?